# Internet Explorer/Microsoft EdgeからHTMLを編集する方法

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

セキュリティの勉強をしています。
セキュリティを上げるために自作のHPのハッキングをしています。
XSS(クロスサイトスクリプティング)でブラウザからHTMLを編集するというやり方を試しています。
Google Chromeからは簡単にできたのですが、Microsoft Edge/Internet ExplorerからはHTMLを編集するやり方が分かりません。

Chromeでは右クリックしてソースを開いて編集しました。

ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

利用環境追記：
Windows10
Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer11

Comment: 環境を質問文中に含めた方が良いです。`編集`から修正が可能ですのでお願いします。

Comment: どこい環境が関わってくるのでしょうか？もう少し詳細教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 1.InternetExplorerのバージョンにより変わります。2.Window10ではMicrosoftEdgeがIEの代わりに利用されています。`開発者ツール`という単語が質問文中になかったので、可能な限り認識のズレを少なくするために必要でした。また、バージョンにより挙動が変わる可能性もあるため、基本的には開発環境の情報を記載した方がいいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>F12</kbd>を押下して`開発者ツール`を開くことが出来ますか？
IE11なら開くことが出来るはずですが、
稀に開けない場合があるので、その場合はレジストリの値を下記のように変更します。
(古いバージョンのIEの場合は別でインストールする必要があったような気がします。)
(ほか、グループポリシーで制限されている場合もあります。)
(また、開発者ツールはIE8以上で利用できるツールになります。)

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
　└ `SOFTWARE`
　　　└ `Policies`
　　　　　└ `Microsoft`
　　　　　　　└ `Internet Explorer`
　　　　　　　　　└ `IEDevTools`
`Disabled=0`

Comment: ……IEじゃないじゃん、というツッコミは無粋ですかね。とりあえずEdge向けのリンクを置いておきます。開発者ツールが起動しない場合は参考にして下さい。https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/developer-settings-gp

Comment: アイコンが似ていたためIEだと思って使用していたものがMicrosoft Edgeだったことが分かりました。（正確にはwindows10からはIEがなくなりEdgeになっていると思ったので、二つとも使用できることを知りませんでした。）環境の確認をという指摘がなければ気づかなかったです、ありがとうざいます。IEでも動作の確認できました。

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+IでHTMLソースでました。

Comment: Microsoft EdgeならばCtrl+Shift+iで要素を表示できますね。大文字のiと小文字のlが判別しにくかったのでコメントで捕捉させていただきました。